# How to retry indefinitely while connecting spring boot application to consul

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, consul, spring-cloud-consul

We use Consul by HashiCorp for configuration management in our spring boot application. Sometimes consul agent is occasionally unavailable when our app starts. It is inconvenient that the app fails if consul isn’t available for configuration.

I read about Consul Retry https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.2.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-consul.html#spring-cloud-consul-retry

Although it is a good solution for retrying, is there any solution in which the application retries indefinitely until it connects with consul?

We deploy this app on tomcat. Is there a better solution than consul-retry for reconnection? Should we try reloading app on tomcat whenever it fails ?

Can anyone tell me the best practice for reconnection in this scenario?

Comment: We use `spring.cloud.consul.retry.*` configuration properties and change/set the number of retry attempts to a large value (than the default 6) and slightly increase the exponential multiplier. Not sure of best practices, but this so far has worked.